# How to read JSON files

Tags: java, json, eclipse, http, jackson

I have a result from Google GeoCode in format of JSON as shown image#1. I am interested in the values indicated in red line.

I tried unsuccefully to do in way shown in image#2

[image: Received JSOn and code to read]
[Received JSOn and code to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKRlW.png)

**Here is interesting thing on debug,** variables i am interested are **NOT** in 'variable' filed as shown in image#4

But if i click to top element, it shows the elements which are invisible, image#4

[image: debug screenshots]
[debug screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsyPU.jpg)

So, How can i get only interested fields form JSON HTTP response ?

**Disclaimer:Due to less reputation only 2 links are allowed so need to merge picture**

Comment: You can create new Array List and put on it just the interested fields from filteredHotels Array List

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this;

[Sample Boilerplate Code to Parse GeoCode API Response and extract necessary parameter values](https://gist.github.com/code-4-fun/63c18768785a85b89c6c8ff41b8f4b27)